# Java Thread join() behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, join

```
public class RunTest {
    public static int counter = 0;
    static class RunnerDec implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<5000; i++){
                counter--;
            }
        }
    }

    static class RunnerInc implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<5000; i++){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunnerDec rd = new RunnerDec();
        RunnerInc ri = new RunnerInc();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(rd);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ri);
        t1.start();     
        t2.start();
        try{
            t1.join(); // this will stop the main thread until t1 is done incrementing 5000 times
            t2.join(); // this will stop the main thread until t2 is done incrementing 5000 times
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

}
```

> I expect the result to be 0 every time alas this is not the case.  The java doc says join() "waits for this thread to die".  I feel like the main thread should wait for t1 to finish then wait for t2 to finish.  That's not what is happening.  Thanks for the clarity!!

Comment: What do you think `start` does?

Answer (score 2):

It does wait for the threads to die. But your two threads concurrently update a shared variable without any synchronization, so you're seeing race conditions and visibility issues.

For example:

```
counter = 1000
thread 1 reads counter : 1000
thread 2 reads counter : 1000
thread 1 increments and writes counter: 1001
thread 2 decrements and writes counter: 999
```

Since ++ and -- are not atomic operations, the above thread interlacing example loses an increment.

The easiest way to fix them is to use an AtomicInteger rather than an int. To understand the crux of the problem, you'd better read Java Concurrency in Practice, or at the very least the Java concurrency tutorial.